# Redis Distributed Lock Ordering Guarantees?

Tags: redis, locking, distributed

I'm using Redis as a distributed lock. Is it possible to guarantee that locks are given out in the order requested?

For example, I have 3 requesters asking for a lock: A, B, and C. Both A and B request the lock simultaneously with A getting the lock. Some time later while B is waiting for the lock to be released, C also requests the lock.

Can I guarantee that B will get the lock first? Or is it possible C will get the lock before B? Is there an algorithm I can use to guarantee B gets the lock first?

Comment: No, there's no such guarantee, and C might get lock before B.

Comment: I figured. To make this work you'd need a queue of who is waiting for the lock, and then need to account for processes in the queue that have crashed, stopped waiting, etc. which is non-trivial.